# How to set --summary in the test assembly in Expecto

Tags: unit-testing, f#, expecto

Expecto allows you to set parameters via CLIArguments and also by overriding its `defaultConfig`. One of the parameters is `--summary`. Currently I just directly pass "--summary" and merge it with `argv` but is there a parameter (I assume 'printer') that can be overridden? In that case, how? This is what I do now:

```
open Expecto
open Expecto.Impl
open Expecto.Logging

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let defaultConfig = {
            defaultConfig with
                colour = Logging.Colour256
                verbosity = LogLevel.Info
        }
    let argv = Array.append argv [|"--summary"|]
    Tests.runTestsInAssembly defaultConfig argv
```

Comment: I'd change the name of your `defaultConfig` and call it just `config` or `customConfig`. Because it's no longer the default since you're changing some values, so the name `defaultConfig` is no longer really true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [source code](https://github.com/haf/expecto/blob/d182de583f33ac46d5bbe0d4548218971edd355c/Expecto/Expecto.fs#L1869)

```ml
| Summary -> fun o -> {o with printer = TestPrinters.summaryPrinter o.printer}
```

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. So the defaultConfig should have `printer = TestPrinters.summaryPrinter defaultConfig.printer`.